# Can jQuery make 2 different variables with the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery is JavaScript. So, you have 2 different ways to declare a variable:

- The jQuery way
- The JavaScript way

Is this:

```
$variable = "string";
```

The same as this:

```
var variable = "string";
```

Or declare you 2 different variables?

Comment: `jQuery` doesn't make variables. It's a library written in `Javascript`. That's the one handling variables.

Comment: `$` is just a character that JavaScript allows in identifiers. It has nothing specifically to do with jQuery.

Comment: There is no "jQuery way".  `$` is a normal character that can appear in any name.

Comment: And you got something else really wrong here. The difference between your _2 ways_ is the variable name and the use of `var`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is _dangerously_ confused.

Comment: Read this before continuing with anything you're planning to do: [Values, variables, and literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Comment: Downvoters, please be aware that not every person is at the same level of programming.  If someone has a genuine question about syntax, it belongs here even if it is not overly complicated.

Comment: Agree with the above statement. call-me, I recommend you learn more Javascript before touch-basing on JQuery. Remember that JQuery is not some super language, it is just Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$variable = "string";` is not a "jQuery way" to make a variable in JavaScript.  If the JavaScript code is not being run in strict mode, then that statement will implicitly declare `$variable` as a var, just as any assignment would.  `var variable = "string";` would declare a variable named `variable`, and so you'd have 2 separate variables; `$variable` and `variable`.  None of this would be affected by jQuery.

Note that variables are often prefixed with `$` to denote that they are jQuery-wrapped objects, eg.

```
var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');
```

Answer (score 4):

jquery is an library of javascript so syntax of declaring is same

`$variable` and `variable` are different variables

Starting with "$" may be a convention followed by any writer to identify things.

In javascript variable names can  begin with `$` and `_`

variable names are case sensitive so `variable=""` something and `Variable` are also different.